# How to use recaptcha invisible?

Tags: laravel, invisible-recaptcha

I have a contact form in my laravel website. I added an invisble recaptcha. This is my code :

```
<div class="contact-form-ftr">
     <form method="post" action="{{ route('contact.store') }}" id="form" data-toggle="validator">
          <div class="form-group pmd-textfield pmd-textfield-floating-label col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 no-padding contact-padding">
                   <label class="control-label">
                          Nom
                   </label>
                   <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group pmd-textfield pmd-textfield-floating-label col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                   <label class="control-label">
                          Email
                   </label>
                   <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required>
           </div>
                           
           <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="_____"  data-size="invisible"></div>
                   <div class="send text-right" {{-- style="margin-top: 200px" --}}>
                          <button type="submit" class="red-btn-send"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Envoyer </button >
                   </div>
      </form>
</div>
```

I cannot submit the form once all the inputs are filled .

Answer (score 0):

Register new captcha select Invisible reCAPTCHA badge option(Invisible reCAPTCHA badge option available in reCAPTCHA v2).

[image]

Comment: that's what i did i followed all the steps i had a recaptcha v2 before so i'm familiar with the concept i just wanted to change to a visible recpatcha instead of i'm not a robot

Comment: I suggest this site to follow the steps.https://laravel-news.com/invisible-recaptcha-integration-with-laravel

Comment: compatible with laravel 4.2 ?

Comment: I have searched for that.it is compatible with laravel version 4.2.

Comment: will try to implement it then